# Upgrading some Corda3 source code to run on v4

Tags: kotlin, corda

First of all, I've only started learning corda 3 months ago so I've got some learning to do.

I've inherited some code that runs fine under Corda v3.3 but the customers want it to run on v4.  I'm trying to follow the instructions on the main website. I've got an initiating flow which calls a subflow, which in turn calls a transponder flow.

The initiating flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow(version = 2)
@StartableByRPC
class TransferFlow(private val issuerName: String = "",
                   private val seller: String = "",
                   private val amount: BigDecimal = BigDecimal("0"),
                   private val buyer: String = "",
                   private val custodianNameOfBuyer: String = "",
                   private val notaryName: String = "") : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

        subFlow(UpdateStatusOfTransferFlow(
                sessions,
                tokenTransferAgreement.linearId,
                "Removed Tokens From Seller"))
  }
}

class UpdateStatusOfTransferFlow(
        private val sessions: Set<FlowSession>,
        private val tokenTransferAgreementID: UniqueIdentifier,
        private val newStatus: String) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        sessions.size
        val idQueryCriteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(tokenTransferAgreementID))
        val states = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<TokenTransferAgreement>(idQueryCriteria).states

        if (states.size != 1) throw FlowException("Can not find a unique state for $tokenTransferAgreementID")

        val inputStateAndRef = states.single()
        val inputState = inputStateAndRef.state.data

        val notary = inputStateAndRef.state.notary

        val outputState = inputState.withNewStatus(newStatus)

        val cmd = Command(TokenContract.Commands.UpdateStatusOfTransfer(),
                inputState.participants.map { it.owningKey })


        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
        txBuilder.addCommand(cmd)
        txBuilder.addInputState(inputStateAndRef)
        txBuilder.addOutputState(outputState, TokenContract.ID)

        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)
        val ptx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)
        val sessions2 = (inputState.participants.toSet() - ourIdentity).map { initiateFlow(it) }

       return subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(ptx, sessions2))

    }

}

And the responder:

@InitiatedBy(TransferFlowResponder::class)
class UpdateStatusOfTransferFlowResponder(private val session: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val tokenTransferAgreements = mutableListOf<TokenTransferAgreement>()
        var isBuyer = true
        var notary = CordaUtility.getNotary(serviceHub) ?: throw FlowException("An notary is expected!")

        val signedTransactionFlow = subFlow(object : SignTransactionFlow(session) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                "There must be one output!" using (stx.tx.outputStates.size == 1)

                val tokenTransferAgreement = stx.tx.outputStates.first() as TokenTransferAgreement
                tokenTransferAgreements.add(tokenTransferAgreement)

                notary = stx.notary ?: throw FlowException("An notary is expected!")

                if (ourIdentity == tokenTransferAgreement.issuer) {
                   //checks go here
                 }

        })
    }

}
```

I believe I am supposed to add a call to ReceiveFinality flow at some point, however it only takes 1 session as an argument, not a list as I have here. Should I make multiple calls, one for each session? I am also not sure if the calls should go in the transponder or the UpdateStatusOfTransferFlow class.

Help here would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need FinalityFlow. and in the responder you need to call ReceiveFinalityFlow before you return. https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt

Answer (score 0):

The FinalityFlow is mainly responsible for ensuring transactions are notarized, distributed accordingly and persisted to local vaults.

In previous versions of Corda, all nodes would by default accept incoming requests for finality.

From V4 onwards, you're required to write a ReceiveFinalityFlow to write your own processing logic before finality.

The way finality currently runs in Corda is the initiating node, as an intermediate step during finality, distributes notarised transaction to all other participants. Each of the participating nodes it sends to will only expect to receive a session from this node.

So where you might submit multiple sessions to the initiating FinalityFlow to include all the participants, the responding nodes will only ever receive just the one session from the initiator.

In the future, we may look at having the Notary distribute the notarized transaction to all participants, but even then, the ReceiveFinalityFlow would still only expect one session, this time from the Notary.